# $\ell_2$ convergence and $\ell_1$ norm convergence implies $\ell_1$ convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let $x_n \in \ell_2$ converge to $x_\infty \in \ell_2$ and $||x_n||_1$ converge to $||x_\infty||_1$ where $||\cdot||_1$ is $\ell_1$ norm. Is it true, that $x_n$ converge to $x_\infty$ in $\ell_1$?

Comment: can you prove that if $x_n$ converges to $x$ pointwise and $\|x_n\|_{l^1}$ converges to $\|x\|_{l^1}$ then $\|x_n-x\|_{l^1} \to 0$ ? (hint : start by showing that for every $N$ : $x_n(1:N)$ converges to $x(1:N)$ in $l^1$)

Comment: and maybe you should read Tao's blog : https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/ (Example 1,2,3,4) for getting an intuition about those questions

Comment: Thanks, I will read it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if you allow $||x_\infty||_1=\infty$: let $$x_n(j)=
\begin{cases}
1/j,&(1\le j\le n),
\\0,&(j>n).\end{cases}$$

Yes if $||x_\infty||_1<\infty$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $A$ so $$\sum_{j=A+1}^\infty|x_\infty(j)|<\epsilon.$$Since convergence in $\ell^2$ implies pointwise convergence there exists $N$ so that $$\left|\vert \vert x_n\vert\vert_1-\vert\vert x_\infty\vert\vert_1\right|<\epsilon\quad(n>N)$$and $$\sum_{j=1}^A|x_n(j)-x_\infty(j)|<\epsilon\quad(n>N).$$The triangle  inequality implies $$\sum_{j=1}^A|x_n(j)|\ge\left(\sum_{j=1}^A|x_\infty(j)|\right)-\epsilon\ge||x_\infty||_1-2\epsilon\quad(n>N),$$hence $$\sum_{j=A+1}^\infty|x_n(j)|<3\epsilon\quad(n>N),$$which shows finally that $$||x_n-x_\infty||_1<5\epsilon\quad(n>N).$$

---

**In fact** the same holds for any measure space. Say $\mu$ is a measure on $X$, $||f_n-f||_2\to0$, $||f||_1<\infty$ and $||f_n||_1\to||f||_1$. Start by choosing a set $E$ with $\mu(E)<\infty$ and $$\int_{X\setminus E}|f|\,d\mu<\epsilon,$$and use the fact that $$\int_E|f_n-f|\,d\mu\le(\mu(E))^{1/2}||f_n-f||_2.$$

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: he wrote that $\|x_n\|_{l^1}\to \|x_\infty\|_{l^1} $, it should mean that $\|x_\infty\|_{l^1} < \infty$.

Comment: @user1952009 Not necessarily, some people do work with limits in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$.

Comment: @user1952009 ??? Probably $||x_\infty||_1<\infty$ is the only case he really had in mind, but no that doesn't follow from $||x_n||_1\to||x_\infty||_1$.

Comment: what ?? if $\|x_n\|_1 \to \|x\|_1$ then it means that $x \in l^1$ ... you know as me that we never write $\|x\|_1$  for $x \not \in l^1$ (and hence $\|x\|_1$ is nether $+\infty$)

Comment: @user1952009 If you say so. Not by the definitions I've always used.

Comment: but I agree with you that if you consider in the same time the $l^2$ and $l^1$ norm, then the logical definition is for any sequence: $\|x\|_{l^1} = \sum_k |x_k|$ and hence it can be $\infty$ (which is more a function $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^+ \cup \infty$ than a norm)

Comment: @user1952009 It depends... Since $x$ is in $\ell^1$ means $\Vert x\Vert_{\ell^1}<\infty$. You can talk about $\Vert x\Vert_{\ell^{1}}$ where $x$ is not a $\ell^{1}$-sequence. This is merely a function $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\to \mathbb{R}^{+}\cup{\infty}:(x_n)_{n}\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\vert x_{i}\vert$ and we define $\ell^{1}$ as the set $\{(x_{n})_{n}\subset \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{n}}\mid \Vert (x_{n})_{n}\Vert_{\ell^1}}<\infty\}$ in order to make $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\ell^{1}}$ a norm when restricted to $\ell^{1}$.